# Unable to handle events when Adding control at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I am in need of adding arr of type label at run-time.

I am making a program which will retrieve employee name from database in different label.

On clicking each employee name (label) it will display all the information about that employee in a msgbox.

I use the following code to create the label. Since the number of labels is not fixed I have used an array.

```
dim withevents lblArr() as Label 'declared in the class
```

In the subroutine(Form load):

```
   for i as integer=0 to NoofEmployee-1
       redim lblArr(NoofEmployee-1)
       lblArr(i)=new Label
       ' i assigned all the necessary property like size location etc..
       me.controls.add(lblArr(i))
   next
```

I declared another subroutine:

```
private sub MyClick(sender as Object,e as EventArgs) **handles lblArr(0).click**
  MsgBox("Hello")
end sub
```

The code doesnt compile since a subroutine doesn't

Comment: Support this kind of Handles clause I suppose.  Yes, use AddHandler.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `AddHandler` to link an event handler to a control.

[Look at this guide](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/EventHandler.aspx).

Comment: The code doesnt compile since a subroutine doesn't handle any control array event. (handles lblArr(0).click)

Comment: Get rid of the `Handles xxx` and like I said, use `AddHandler` to link the event handler to the control.

Comment: +1 Correct solution but you haven't explained *why* Pramod is getting this problem. I suggest you say "You need to use `AddHandler` to **dynamically** link an event handler to a control **in an array. `Handles` doesn't support controls in arrays**"

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define a function that will act as the event handler:

```
Private Sub DynamicLabel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Do something, such as ...
    Dim labelText as String = String.Empty

    lableText = DirectCast(sender, Label).Text

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The text of the Label is {0}", labelText)

End Sub
```

Then, when you dynamically create your Label controls, you need to tell the control to use your custom event handler function:

```
Dim lbl As New Label

With lbl

    ' Set the properties of the Label here ...

   ' Now, tell the Label what function to use when clicked.
    AddHandler .Click, AddressOf DynamicLabel_Click

End With

Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

Notice that I did not use an array ... don't think VB6 control arrays. They aren't really necessary. Instead, I added the control to a container (Panel1 in this example). The `sender` object in sub `DynamicLabel_Click` will contain the reference to which Label has been clicked.